# Add Opening Monthly value, Closing Monthly value and Average of these two values as three separate columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a single table that looks like this:

| DATE | COUNTRY | CUSTOMER_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/23 | Germany | 1 |
| 01/03/23 | Germany | 1 |
| 02/03/23 | France | 3 |
| 05/03/23 | UK | 1 |
| 10/03/23 | Spain | 5 |
| 31/03/23 | Germany | 2 |

My requirement is as follows:

1. Group the table by month + year, country, customer type
2. Add a column [OPENING_VALUE] counting all rows that have a date of the first of the month (grouped by the month, country and customer type)
3. Add a column [CLOSING_VALUE] counting all rows that have a date of the last of the month (grouped by the month, country and customer type)
4. Add a column [AVERAGE_VALUE] that averages the [OPENING_VALUE] and [CLOSING_VALUE] for each month.

It should look something like this:

| DATE | COUNTRY | CUSTOMER_TYPE | OPENING_VALUE | CLOSING_VALUE | AVERAGE_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/23 | Germany | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 03/23 | France | 1 | 17 | 25 | 21 |
| 03/23 | UK | 1 | 100 | 150 | 125 |
| 03/23 | Spain | 1 | 5 | 10 | 7.5 |
| 04/23 | Germany | 2 | 15 | 20 | 17.5 |
| 04/23 | France | 2 | 50 | 100 | 75 |

...

Thanks!

Comment: you must add the original table, so that we can build your result

Comment: This is basic SQL stuff have you read about GROUP BY?   Have you tried anything, why can't you solve this problem.?  This website is not a place where we solve the problem for you, we are not consultants -- if you need one of those, you can hire them.  Instead if you have an issue with code that you think should work we can help in that case.  What have you tried?

Comment: Well its a little more complicated than GROUP BY isn't it. GROUP BY only solves the first requirement - did you read the next three? My issue is that no matter what combination of window functions or subqueries that I've tried, I keep getting stuck on how to count rows only for the first and last days of the months (ignoring all days inbetween) and display these as separate columns. The average part is easy but its steps 2 and 3 which are causing me problems.

Of course, you're not "consultants" though so feel free to ignore this and go and be unhelpful to somebody else instead :)

Comment: ok I will show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you find the "first" and "last" day of the month (assuming these are the first and last referenced days since day 1 would always be the first day but isn't in your example data.)

```
WITH numbered AS (
  SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY DAY(date) ASC as RN_FIRST,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY DAY(date) DESC as RN_LAST
  FROM sometableyoudidntname
)
SELECT *, F.Date as FIRST_DATE, L.Date as LAST_DATE
FROM sometableyoudidntname X
LEFT JOIN numbered F ON F.Customer = X.Customer AND F.date = X.date AND RN_FIRST = 1
LEFT JOIN numbered L ON L.Customer = X.Customer AND L.date = X.date AND RN_LAST = 1
```

Now that you know the date of the first and the last items you should be able to do the group by

NOTE:  It is not exactly clear to me if I am using the right partition and joins.  This depends on what drives the uniqueness of your data model.

Answer (score 0):

It's really helpful if you provide DDL/DML that's easy to reproduce when you ask questions like this.
Your result set doesn't seem to match the example data you provided.

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Date DATE, Country NVARCHAR(50), Customer_type INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (Date, Country, Customer_type) VALUES 
('2023-03-01', 'Germany', 1),
('2023-03-01', 'Germany', 1),
('2023-03-02', 'France', 3),
('2023-03-05', 'UK', 1),
('2023-03-10', 'Spain', 5),
('2023-03-31', 'Germany', 2);
```

Using this we just need to be able to flag the first and last day values, and then aggregate on that:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Date) AS VARCHAR),2)+'/'+RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,Date) AS VARCHAR),2) AS Date, Country, Customer_type, COUNT(a.Opening_Value) AS Opening_Value, AVG(.0+a.Average_Value) AS Average_Value, COUNT(a.Closing_Value) AS Closing_Value
  FROM (
SELECT Date, Country, Customer_type, 
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Date) = 1 THEN 1 END AS Opening_Value, 
       1 AS Average_Value, 
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) = 1 THEN 1 END AS Closing_Value
  FROM @Table
       ) a
 GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,Date), DATEPART(YEAR,Date), Country, Customer_type
```

| Date | Country | Customer_type | Opening_Value | Average_Value | Closing_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/23 | France | 3 | 0 | 1.000000 | 0 |
| 03/23 | Germany | 1 | 2 | 1.000000 | 0 |
| 03/23 | Germany | 2 | 0 | 1.000000 | 1 |
| 03/23 | Spain | 5 | 0 | 1.000000 | 0 |
| 03/23 | UK | 1 | 0 | 1.000000 | 0 |

As a side note, when using dates it's a good idea to use the [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) of `yyyy-mm-dd` as it removes any ambiguity.

Comment: You are assuming that the first day of month and last day of month are the opening and closing -- I think the OP wants the earliest day and last day in the month

Comment: OP explicitly said `[OPENING_VALUE] counting all rows that have a date of the first of the month` and `[CLOSING_VALUE] counting all rows that have a date of the last of the month`

Comment: and their example data and results contradicts that.  My experience is that what OPs say rarely is directly what they mean -- just associated with it. :)

Comment: The result set they provided also shows France with 17...
Those dates are `DD/MM/YY` all for March 2023.
Both of these points are addressed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks both for your input - @PatrickHurst, your answer was the one I was looking for and worked - I just needed to adjust the `Average_Value` calculation as the answer is always 1 in your solution (or at least when I applied it) but this was a minor point. I switched `AVG(.0+a.Average_Value)` to `(COUNT(a.Opening_Value) + COUNT(a.Closing_Value)) / 2 AS Average_Value`.

As a point of clarification, my result set assumed there were many more rows in the sample table to make it clear what the `Average_Value` column was doing without having to manually write out dozens of rows.